# Error using CMD-R on a Cucumber feature in TextMate

Tags: cucumber, textmate, textmatebundles

Running a Cucumber feature from inside TextMate is producing an error.
Works perfectly from the terminal

error is:

> Running: /usr/local/bin/ruby /Users/craig/Projects/lahaina/script/cucumber /Users/craig/Projects/lahaina/features/top_level_pages.feature --format=html Missing these required gems: cucumber-rails >= 0.3.2 database_cleaner >= 0.5.0 webrat >= 0.7.0 You're running: ruby 1.8.7.174 at /usr/local/bin/ruby rubygems 1.3.7 at /Users/craig/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems. Using the default profile... false

If I check my gems with 'gem query' i can clearly see that the mentioned gems are installed:

> cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
>   database-cleaner (0.5.2)
>   webrat (0.7.1)

running 'rake gems:install' as suggested has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a combination of issues:

Removed all the gems etc. back to almost a bare install and reinstalled ruby, rails, cucumber and rspec and it all started working again.